# How to count entries with specific time range in Excel?

Tags: excel, windows, macos

Can anyone help me with this brain teaser :)

I need to count entries by hour and date and as the list is huge formula will save my life.

Bellow is the example how it looks.

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
17/05/2017 00:40
17/05/2017 01:10
17/05/2017 04:30
17/05/2017 05:00
17/05/2017 05:00
17/05/2017 05:05
17/05/2017 05:15
17/05/2017 05:20
17/05/2017 05:20
17/05/2017 05:30
17/05/2017 05:30
17/05/2017 05:30
17/05/2017 05:40
17/05/2017 05:45
17/05/2017 05:45
17/05/2017 05:50
17/05/2017 06:00
17/05/2017 06:00
17/05/2017 06:00
17/05/2017 06:20
17/05/2017 06:25
```

Comment: So what would your output look like?

Comment: 00:00 - 00:55 1
01:00 - 01:55 1
02:00 - 02:55 0
03:00 - 03:55 0
04:00 - 04:55 1
05:00 - 05:55 13 
06:00 - 06:55 5

Comment: @ScottCraner it should look something like that

Comment: Is your data in one column, or two (date in one, time another)?

Comment: @BruceWayne Date and time is in one column.

Comment: Do you care about the date, or do you just want to count the hours regardless of date?

Comment: @ScottCraner To be honest time is the most important, as the data can be exported by date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it with your date and times in one column use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD($A$1:$A$21,1)>=C1)*(MOD($A$1:$A$21,1)<=D1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Scott, the issue that i have now that my date format is different and it does not work :)

Comment: So you get a date that is `dd/mm/yyyy` and your local settings are `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: If the date and time is in one column, just use DATA --> Text to Columns, and use `SPACE` as the delimiter to put them in to two columns. There may be other ways to get your answer, keeping the info in one column, but that would likely be a relatively convoluted/complex formula. Text to Columns allows for quicker analysis.

If your data is in two columns, you can use `COUNTIFS()`:

`=COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$21,">="&E1,$B$1:$B$21,"<="&F1)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in one column, then add to the right column the following formula

```
=REPLACE(REPT(REPT("0",2-LEN(HOUR(A1)))&HOUR(A1),2),3,0,":00 - ")&":55"
```

and then use pivot table to count each group
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yFSV.png)

Comment: @pnuts Do you mean that Pivot Table can group numbers/timestamps ? is there any documentation you can link here ?

Comment: Of course I know this way. But if he got a long list of timestamps it will be pretty hard to do.

Comment: But list is sorted by date and time and not just hour